# Mongoose: Best/Fastest way to do multiple updates that are all slightly different

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema of `Customers`. I want to pull the entire collection (say, 100,000 documents), run some of the customer's properties through an algorithm (purchase history, location, etc.) and assign each customer a `score` based on the results of the algorithm, then save that `score` in their `MongoDB` document. Every customer's `score` will be slightly different.

What is the best way to do this? Right now I am using a loop with each customer and using `findOneAndUpdate` one at a time. Is there a better/faster way?